# How to trigger a function in javascript if the browser cookie is deleted directly?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, cookies, mozilla

Is there any way to trigger a function in javascript when the browser cookie is deleted directly.. ? i want to solve this problem for all the browsers...atleast in major browsers...Please help me to get through this.

Comment: I think you'd need to poll periodicaly (like every 500s or so) for the cookie existence and fire a function if it's not there.

Comment: i tried it and its working fine.. but will it be consuming the browser usage alot ?

Comment: It's a simple operation and shouldn't be a noticeable performance hit, especially if not performed too often (I'd consider 100ms or less of interval "too often").